# Solr result order is wrong when applying sorting (Apache solr with Magento)

Tags: apache, magento, sorting, solr

I am using apache solr 4.6 with Magento EE 1.12

Currently when I am searching **S26** from solr using sorting field (attr_sort_name_en) it wont give the correct order of the result set[image: Solr search with sorting field (attr_sort_name_en)]

But search result order is showing correct order if you don't add the sorting field.

[image: Result without sorting field]

Can anyone explain me what is the reason for this?

following are some important tags from schema.xml file which I thought that is relevant here.

```
<fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>  
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<dynamicField name="attr_sort_*" type="alphaOnlySort"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: The first seems to be sorted, while the latter not? Considering you have start=4785 in the first, it seems reasonable that something around R/S would be returned? .. and the second isn't being sorted by the field, as the results appear sorted by score instead.

Comment: The problem is when sorting applied product names not coming correctly
according to the sorting `S26` appear somewhere in page 4785

I want that name to be appear first
say `S26`
Results should appear as S26, S26 A, S26 Product, SA product, SB Product, ... A product, B Product, C products.... so on.

Comment: When you're asking for a sort, you're telling Solr to ignore all scores / weights / relevance for the fields, and just order the documents according to the order from the field. The only relevant information is whether there's a match or not (the document is in the result set), and not the quality of the match (which is the standard search functionality).

Comment: Cant I do like this? Lets say I have following product Names

(AAA,BBB,CCC,SSS,S26,SSA,ZZZ)

when I search `S26` with applying the sorting through the solr query, I want the result like below.

S26,SSA,SSS,AAA,BBB,CCC,ZZZ

Is this possible?

Comment: Not that I know of, as the sorting seems rather arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I found out the issue. I changed the following in my schema.xml. it was a easy fix with spending lots of searches.

schema.xml

under analyzer type="query" tag change **splitOnNumerics=0**

```
   <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
    generateWordParts="5" generateNumberParts="5" splitOnNumerics="0"
    catenateWords="5" catenateNumbers="5" catenateAll="1" 
    splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" protected="protwords_en.txt"/>
```